# How to change the text size by hovering the mouse over another image?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a website that has a mousetrap that when the mouse hovers on top of a image of a mousetrap, the text changes size.

```
var mousetrap5 = document.getElementById('mousetrap-5');
var blogText = document.getElementById('blog-text');
mousetrap5.onmouseover = function() {
 blogText.fontSize = '100px';
 blogText.style.fontsize = '100px';
}
```

I've changed the 4th and 5th line to `'100px'` so that the changes will be more visible, but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried `blogText.style.fontSize`?

Comment: notice the capital S of the previous answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element.style.fontSize

```js
var mousetrap5 = document.getElementById('mousetrap-5');
var blogText = document.getElementById('blog-text');
mousetrap5.onmouseover = function() {
 blogText.fontSize = '100px';
 blogText.style.fontSize = '100px';
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1 id="mousetrap-5">Test</h1>
<span id="blog-text">ABCDE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally I'd use a comment for a fix to a typo. But I created the snippet to easily demonstrate the correct code.

Comment: You shouldn't even post an answer. You should instead vote to close the question due to a typo. This question won't have any value to anyone else in the future, as with all typo related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to capitalize the "S" in `fontSize`. See below! :)

```js
var mousetrap5 = document.getElementById('mousetrap-5');
var blogText = document.getElementById('blog-text');
mousetrap5.onmouseover = function() {
  blogText.style.fontSize = '100px';
}
```

```html
<div id="mousetrap-5">
  <span id="blog-text">Hello World</span>
</div>
```